# indexing error on the bin size generation,

Tags: pandas, numpy, histogram

I am trying to bin data

```
def binned(cols, bins, labels):
"""helper method that puts proper bin values in proper rows of pandas df"""
    for col in cols:
        yield ('{}_bin'.format(col), labels[np.digitize(calProbDf[col], bins)])

        year2017    year2016    year2015    year2014    year2013    year2012    year2011    year2010    year2009    year2008    year2007    year2006    year2005    year2004    year2003    year2002    year2001    year2000    year1999
0   0   2302688.000 2413693.000 2256486.000 2168558.000 2066282.000 1985939.000 1951843.000 1931046.000 1923389.000 2097383.000 2244158.000 2044425.000 2008856.000 1885044.000 1808412.000 1717079.000 1672181.000 1117481.000 1496984.000
1   1   1362965.000 1350909.000 1327282.000 1313024.000 1305272.000 1337781.000 1338887.000 1327547.000 1259782.000 948843.000  868455.000  862390.000  841620.000  768903.000  765313.000  748585.000  447990.000  326099.000  253401.000
2   2   772403.000  778213.000  751895.000  748270.000  794325.000  701705.000  713557.000  745222.000  779142.000  898040.000  900440.000  902645.000  914607.000  933216.000  946243.000  1302167.000 1043364.000 1091437.000 1098097.000
3   3   760653.000  727597.000  683742.000  641941.000  616501.000  605726.000  601817.000  605987.000  633514.000  618503.000  576404.000  544912.000  522607.000  498113.000  466032.000  426481.000  383305.000  356646.000  333690.000
4   4   704425.000  703839.000  693907.000  696804.000  706696.000  727458.000  742575.000  746332.000  729393.000  721906.000  699326.000  711959.000  671249.000  583177.000  580600.000  576899.000  568372.000  576476.000  555458.000
```

I use following method to generate the bins

```
dit='0123456789'

    binDefined = np.array([5, 10, 15, 20, 30, 50, 75, 100, 150,  200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500, 600,
                  700, 800, 900, 1000, 1200, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900, 2000, 3000,
                  4000, 5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 25000, 30000, 50000, 100000, 200000, np.inf])


def id_generator(size=6, chars=string.digits):
    """generate a nonunique bin to avoid double counting"""
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))


binList= np.array(['b_{}'.format(id_generator(2, dit))for i in range(len(binDefined))])

cols = ('year2017', 'year2016', 'year2015', 'year2014',
       'year2013', 'year2012', 'year2011', 'year2010', 'year2009', 'year2008',
       'year2007', 'year2006', 'year2005', 'year2004', 'year2003', 'year2002',
       'year2001', 'year2000', 'year1999')


binnedDF=calProbDf.assign(**dict(binned(cols, binDefined, binList)))
```

when I try to create assigned bins and generate  binnedDF. I get out of range error.

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-e18328775bee> in <module>()
     20 
     21 
---> 22 binnedDF=calProbDf.assign(**dict(binned(cols, binDefined, binList)))
     23 

<ipython-input-7-3cc0b93a043c> in binned(cols, bins, labels)
      1 def binned(cols, bins, labels):
      2     for col in cols:
----> 3         yield ('{}_bin'.format(col), labels[np.digitize(calProbDf[col], bins)])

IndexError: index 42 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 42
```

The length of binList and binDefined is 42. there are 19 columns.

My goal is to classify each data into individual bin based on the binList and binDefined above.

Comment: Try printing the `shape` and `len` of variables in the function `binned`. By the way, this looks convoluted and over-thought for your stated goal. Have you looked into `pandas.cut`? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html

Comment: Peter I have tried pd.cut.  How would you assign binA, binB, upto say about 45 bins using pd.cut for the above data?